How to calculate the rolling Slope and rolling R-squared value in pandas of last 5 periods?
I have 2 columns in my excel sheet. First is SL No which is serial number and second is Close column.
In excel, I could quickly calculate the Slope by using the slope function and then drag it down ( rolling )
Similarly I also calculated the R-squared value by using the RSQ function. I want to do the same in pandas.
How do I calculate the rolling slope and r squared value of these 2 columns (serial number and close)
This is the data -
data = {
"SL no": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
"Close": [46.20, 49.90, 51.85, 54.00, 57.70, 56.60, 52.95, 55.35, 57.20, 58.05, 56.65],
"Ln": [3.83, 3.91, 3.95, 3.99, 4.06, 4.04, 3.97, 4.01, 4.05, 4.06, 4.04]
}

The above is the desired calculation through excel

The above contains the formula used in excel to derive the columns.
This is some code which I tried
def calculate_slope(x, y):
    """Calculate the slope using the last 5 values."""
    if len(x) < 5:
        return np.nan  # Not enough data to compute slope
    slope = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)[0]  # Linear fit (degree 1)
    return slope

df['rolling_slope'] = df['close'].rolling(window=5).apply(lambda x: calculate_slope(df['sno'].iloc[x.index], x), raw=False)

the above code is giving different output than the excel version

We don't know what you're doing in Excel. Could you please give the exact formula that you're using?

I have updated the screenshot above

Answer
In your example, the Exponential function is obviously applied based on the Ln column(C in Excel), but the function you applied in Python is rolling based on the close column.
# apply rolling to df['Ln'] instead of df['close']
df['rolling_slope'] = df['Ln'].rolling(window=5).apply(lambda x: calculate_slope(df['sno'].iloc[x.index], x), raw=False)

As an aside, I think this is a question that could have been easily solved if you had checked your code carefully. Not checking your code is one thing, but your question also seems to have been written without checking for minor errors: the key of the data(dict) you provided is clearly SL no, but the code you used for rolling + apply is df['sno'], close column is different(close or Close), in the 5th line of the excel figure, SL no should get the slope, but it doesn't, etc. Lots of minor errors. The question is poorly explained and has too many minor errors for anyone to answer, and I think you should get in the habit of checking yourself for minor errors to improve your coding.
